# Empty body while posting json to Node JS Express via Fiddler but works with POSTMAN REST Client

Tags: json, node.js, post, express, fiddler

I am trying to make a post request to my NOde JS express server. Here is the server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


var mysql=require('mysql');

app.post('/ignitionInput',function(req, res){
    var jsonRecieved=req.body;
    var accountId=jsonRecieved.AccountId;
    var deviceId=jsonRecieved.DeviceId;
    var latitude=jsonRecieved.Latitude;
    var longitude=jsonRecieved.Longitude;
    var address=jsonRecieved.Address;
    var phoneNumber=jsonRecieved.PhoneNumber;
    var vehicleNumber=jsonRecieved.VehicleNumber;    
    console.log(jsonRecieved);
    connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        //Some db operations
    });
});
```

When I try making request using POSTMAN it sends the correct body but when I make the same request using TELERIK FIDDLER it receives empty body.

I am posting the JSON below:

```
{
    "AccountId":"abhinay",
    "DeviceId":"00000000000000000",
    "Latitude":"28.607835",
    "Longitude":"77.2879133",
    "Address":"Noida Link Road, Pandav Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi 110091, India",
    "PhoneNumber":"23456789066556",
    "VehicleNumber":"DL3C AK 234567"
}
```

**HTTP HEADERS:**

**Fiddler:**

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9999
Content-Length: 276
Content-Type: "application/json"
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**POSTMAN:**

```
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 177
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Sun, 08 Feb 2015 10:53:55 GMT
X-Powered-By → Express
```

Note: I've mentioned Content-Type:"application/json" in the HTTP HEADER

Why is it happening?? Any Ideas??

Comment: @Bhuwan, Did you found the problem and solution ?

Comment: Explicitly define the content type to application/json